# Open Camera or Gallery from " inappbrowser " in Apache Cordova

Tags: cordova, camera, cordova-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, inappbrowser

I have a hybrid application developed using Apache Cordova, within that application I am using " inappbrowser ". Now the requirement is to open Camera or Gallery from the inappbrowser, I am not able to figure out how to achieve this.

For developing this application I am using backbone.js, JQuery, bootstrap.js.

Here is the code snippet of Backbone's View :

```
  var mainScreenView = Backbone.View.extend({

        el: $('.panel'),

        templateMainScreen: _.template($('#templateOne').html()),

        events: {

            "click #inputBtnSubmit": "openWebView",
            "click #clickSettings": "openSettings"
        },

        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },

        render: function () {

            alert($(this.el).find('.panel-body'));
            var bindElement = $(this.el).find('.panel-body');
            bindElement.html(this.templateMainScreen());
            return this;
        },

        openWebView: function () {

            var textValue = $('#inputValue').val();
                       cordova.InAppBrowser.open('**Link to an external webpage which asks for Camera or Gallery control** ', '_blank', 'location=no');

       //  After inappbrowser is called to load a external webpage (On a button click Camera Intent or Gallery should open)
        }

    });

    var appView = new mainScreenView;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't, in app browser can't execute plugins code. The only option is using input type file, it should work, at least on ios

Comment: Ya true jcesarmobile, I ended up in implementing <iframe>. That is, instead of using inappBrowser to display a web page, I used <iframe> to do the work for me. Now I can use Camera or gallery, similar to using a native phone's browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using inappBrowser, i ended up in implementing HTML iframe. That is, What things I wanted inappBrowser to do, now I am able to do using iframe. You can have access to Camera or Gallery or File Explorer, similar to that of a Native Phone's Browser.

Here is what I have done to solve the above problem:

```
   <html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
      <title>Hello World!</title>
      <style type='text/css'>
        body, html, iframe {
                     margin: 0;
                     padding: 0;
                     border: 0px none;
                     width: 100%;
                     height: 100%;
        }
      </style>
 </head>
 <body>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>


     <iframe src="http://SomeWebPage" width="97%" height="97%"></iframe>
 </body>
```

Hope this helps others.

Comment: Can you tell me how you are using the above code to browse or open native camera. I am using https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser this IAB and in this I am calling my external website.

Comment: Nak Android Dev: When you call an external website from an InAppBrowser, you can't access gallery or camera. Therefore in the iFrame tag I opened the external website, from there I was able to access the camera.

Comment: There's html5 tag for `<input type="file>` but this is not working in IAB of npm version, By using File API of html5 it can be opened but issue is in IAB it's not working whereas if I try this in normal page like index.html then it works. So might be this is issue with IAB. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Yes you are right, its because of InAppBrowser you are not able to open. So to overcome this I used iFrame, where I was able to open camera and file explorer.

Comment: Can you tell me complete working example for this. I have tried above code but it's not working in my InAppBrowser.

Comment: can you please provide me solution for issue?

Comment: The mistake you are doing is that, you are the above code to your InAppBrowser code. See that's where you are going wrong. Instead of using InAppBrowser just use "IFRAME" to render what you are trying to render in your InAppBrowser. Then Camera, File Explorer works fine

Comment: My whole app is in IAB; and inside one page i have option to upload image to server so for that purpose i need to browse image inside IAB. For default index.html html5 file api is working fine. but I need solution for IAB.

Comment: hey @ShashankHS .. how to use session created by passport in iframe and the app?

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin if it helps http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.synconset.imagepicker
It should work for inappbrowser.