# Select a photo from gallery/camera InAppBrowser

Tags: android, html, image, cordova, inappbrowser

I have an app with Cordova that execute InAppBrowser, and I need open the contextual menu with the options to get a photo like this: http://puu.sh/nJUP0/433fa31c83.jpg

In Iphone 6 this work but in android not.

I have the input

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" />
```

Comment: Not sure but this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074684/open-camera-or-gallery-from-inappbrowser-in-apache-cordova

Comment: @jaydroider your answer found correctly in HTML without inappbrowser, but I need open Camera or Gallery inside the inappbrowser.

Comment: Give a try using window.open('image/*', '_system', 'location=yes').

Comment: @jaydroider not found, open the url .../image/*

Comment: I think in app browser is only used to open kind of web view for you try else might be iframe.

Comment: @jaydroider the app launch cordova and cordova opened through inappbrowser the webapp

Answer (score 0):

he Camera docs cover this. Is this not working for you? Check out Camera.PictureSourceType for details. The docs site givens this example for deriving an image thus:

```
function getPhoto(source) {
   // Retrieve image file location from specified source
   navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
   destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
   sourceType: source });
}
```

sourceType is the crucial bit here. It can be Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA (the default), or more useful for you it can be Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY or Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM.

[read more](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/fr/3.1.0/cordova/camera/camera.html)

Comment: I've installed the plugin, and execute the app, but inside inappbrowser not work the plugin.
http://puu.sh/nJWK6/2e04034395.png